# Java Mockito Can't mock the result of method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, mocking

I have a problem with testing (mocking the value for method) my delete method from controller . In ordinary mode it works fine but not when I test.

Here is my code.

My Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/deletePost/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<String> deletePost(@PathVariable int id) throws SQLException {
    boolean isRemoved = postsService.deletePost(connection, id);

    if (!isRemoved)
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Post with given id was not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    else {
        modifiedPostsService.insertModificationData(connection, new ModificationData(id, "deletion"));
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Post with given id has been deleted.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
}
```

My PostsService

```
    public boolean deletePost(Connection connection, int id) throws SQLException {
    return postsDao.deletePost(connection, id);
}
```

My PostsDao

```
    @Override
public boolean deletePost(Connection connection, int id) throws SQLException {
    boolean isPostExists = isPostExist(connection, id);
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ps = connection.prepareStatement("delete from POSTS where ID = " + id);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    return isPostExists;
}
```

And finally my tests

```
@WebMvcTest(MainController.class)
class MainControllerTests {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private Connection connection;

@MockBean
private PostsService mockPostsService;

@Test
void testIfDeletePostUrlIsOk() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(mockPostsService.deletePost(connection, 1)).thenReturn(true);
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .delete("/deletePost/1")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

}

`testIfDeletePostUrlIsOk()` returns 404 instead of 200 ( I guess mocking value - true not works, is false instead). Why and how to solve that?

Comment: You just created a local mock of your service, but your controller doesn't use it automatically. You need to inject the mock in some way.

Comment: But I do not know how ;(

Answer (score 2):

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TestingWebApplicationTest {

 @Autowired
 private MockMvc mockMvc;

 @MockBean     
 Connection mockConnection;

 @MockBean
 PostsService mockPostsService;

 @Test
 void testIfDeletePostUrlIsOk() throws Exception {
 Mockito.when(mockPostsService.deletePost(any(), anyInt())).thenReturn(true);
 mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
        .delete("/deletePost/1")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
 }
}
```

You need to inject your mocks into controller, annotation @SpringBootTest and @MockBean will do the work

Comment: Thank you for help but unfortunately it still not works, the same error, 404 instead of 200.

Comment: can you put debug in controller and check if that's your code returning 404? Are you using junit5? Please copy here your imports from testing class

Comment: In controller there can also be 404 code status when there is no post (it's my model) in database with given id otherwise there is 200. I am using JUNIT 5.7.0. Here are some of my imports (not enough space): import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

Comment: Yep I know, that's why I asked you to put debug breakpoint and check if 404 is returned from your controller method or from server application

Comment: I what exactly line I should put a brakepoint? Sorry I am not good with debuging yet.

Comment: Please try with this mock method:
Mockito.when(mockPostsService.deletePost(any(), any())).thenReturn(true); Edited my post

Comment: It gives me an error: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at pl.jawegiel.postswebservice.MainControllerTests.testIfDeletePostUrlIsOk(MainControllerTests.java:38)
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

Comment: Mockito.when(mockPostsService.deletePost(any(), anyInt())).thenReturn(true)

Answer (score 1):

when you use:

```
Mockito.mock(...)
```

you are creating a mock object on your local scope, you have to inject it to your SUT or use:

```
@MockBean
```

[MockBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) will make your object accessible by spring's **ApplicationContext** so spring can pick your mock.

Comment: Thanks for help but nfortunately it still not works, the same error, 404 instead of 200.

Comment: use mockPostsService.deletePost(org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any(Connection.class), 1)   to match any input of type connection, mockito uses object reference to match your method call and your mocks.

Comment: Do you mean this:         Mockito.when(mockPostsService.deletePost(org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any(Connection.class), 1)).thenReturn(true); ?

Comment: exactly, you can import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers too.

Comment: Then I get an error: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:

Comment: you have to use matchers for both arguments, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: So how to add mather for this second argument? It is new to me

Comment: org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyInt()

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)